# Find the values of x at which expression is defined

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

$$f(x)=\frac{\left(x+1\right)\cdot \left(x-1\right)}{\left(x-1\right)\cdot \left(x-2\right)}$$

At which values of x, f(x) is defined?

I think at $x=1,2 $ is not defined. Is it correct or should we cancel $(x-1)$.

Comment: Have you tried graphing the function (by a calculator)? If so, what does the graph tell you?

Comment: No I didn't try graphing the function, we can see here right at x=1, f(x) is $\frac{0}{0}$ which is undefined value

Comment: see even if I plot the graph, I will have to calculate value of f(x) at x=1, but at x=1, f(x) is undefined, so how graphing the function will help.

Answer (score 1):

That's right, $x=1,2$ are not in the domain. Note that, your function $f:\mathbb{R}\setminus\{1,2\}\to\mathbb{R}$ can be written as
$$f(x)=\frac{x+1}{x-2}$$
since we are excluded the value of $1$ and we can cancel out the both factors. This means, the graph of $f$ is the same as the graph of $g:\mathbb{R}\setminus\{2\}\to\mathbb{R}$, where
$$g(x)=\frac{x+1}{x-2}$$
except that the point $(1,g(1))$ appears as a "hole" in the graph of $f$.

Comment: but as per your explanation f(x) and g(x) are different, is it correct?

Comment: the functions are the same, however, they have different domains of operation

Comment: Exactly, the functions are different in this case (only for one point of the domain). It is said that two functions $f$ and $g$ are equal if and only if $\operatorname{dom}(f)=\operatorname{dom}(g)$, $\operatorname{codom}(f)=\operatorname{codom}(g)$ and $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $x$ in the domain.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I have included the graph that was made by Symbolab free online calculator; you can clearly see your predictions to be true!